# Emit each particle while scaling one after another

Tags: particles

How to emit each particle object, so that, say, each instance is scale = 0 when born, and scale = 1 when died? I remember we can do this in 2.49, but things seems being changed in 2.5+, in which the same action is being played simultaneously on all instances, instead of one after another.

Comment: Does [**this addon**](https://vimeo.com/35282479) look like it will help?

Comment: That ability has indeed been discontinued, and is a very big loss. However, there are rumors that an entire new Particle System is being developed by the Blender Institute. For now you can use a workaround like Jerryno's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Add a Texture under the Particle System:

   [image]
2. Set it to gradient(Blend), set the mapping to Particle and influence Size:

   [image]
3. This is what you get:

   [image]
4. The rest is just setting the gradient and default particle size so when they die their size is 1. If they die at random then no, I think this cannot be done without some custom scripted particle generator with frame change handlers.

Comment: I cannot find the Textures panel in Particle tab anymore... I'm using 2.74.4    Quite strange...

Comment: @LeonCheung It is only awailable for Cycles, in Internal this tab is not there but under textures there is now an icon for particle texture.

Comment: I think it is an fairly acceptable solution. Thanks buddy.   :)